# Import Excel template in an existing customzed list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, excel

I would like to import an excel template in a list (tracking to do) that has customized column. Currently, it is empty and I do not want to create tasks line by line in Sharepoint. Do you know a way to proceed?

Kind regards,
Julien

Answer (score 0):

You can use **MS Flow** to realize your design.

---

**Note:**

- Please upload the excel file to Document library.

[image]

- Then, create a List to store content from excel file.

[image]

---

---

1.Add "**Recurrence**" Trigger: You can customize the interval of running flow

2.Add "**List rows present in a table**" Action: Location is your sharepoint site group name

3.Add "**Apply to each**" Action

4.Then, add "**Get items**" Action

5.Add "**Condition**": `length(outputs('Get_items')?['body/value'])` "is not equal" to `0`

- **If yes** : Add "**Apply to each**" Action and add "**Update item**" Action
- **If not** : Add "**Create item**" Action

[image]

In this way, you can add tasks directly in the excel file, and these tasks will be automatically added to the list.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There was a native two-way sync between Excel and SharePoint lists, but it was removed by Microsoft more than 10 years ago.

We have developed a small piece of software that restores that behavior between Excel and SharePoint. You can read more about it and try it here: https://www.synchronizer-for-excel-and-sharepoint.com/

With it, you can have an Excel copy of your SharePoint list. You can then add rows in Excel, or edit existing rows, and send it back to SharePoint.